# Fancybox does not recreate the source element after postback and trigger click

Tags: c#, html, fancybox, postback

When triggering a fancybox click event with RegisterStartupScript after postback, the source element does not get recreated when closing the fancybox.

1. The user opens up the fancybox with a form and submit button as content.
2. The user is able to open and close the fancybox multiple times as expected if not posting the form.
3. When the user hits the submit button a fancybox trigger click scripts gets injected with RegisterStartupScript in order to show the form with a confirmation message directly after the form has successfully been sent. This works as expected.
4. If the user then clicks the close button of the fancybox the source element is not recreated to it's original position in the DOM. So if the user tries to open the fancybox again the content is missing and the fancybox breaks.

I expect the source element to be recreated when closing the fancybox.

Example of code:

```
// Form submit button
FormSubmit.Command += new CommandEventHandler(submit_command);

// Click event
protected void submit_command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{

    // Do stuff         

    // Trigger click event on fancybox in order to reopen the form immediately after postback
    Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "reopen", "$('#OpenFancy').fancybox().trigger('click');", true);
}
```

So the fancybox is reopened as expected but when I close the fancybox and try to open it again the fancybox breaks because the source element has not been copied back to the default position in the DOM.

Comment: I do not know what is postback, but the title of this question is very misleading "Fancybox does not recreate the source element after postback and trigger click" - fancybox does not recreate the source element, because ... it is not supposed to create anything... Also, you should provide some demo  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm using C# together with fancybox. When the user clicks the submit button inside the fancybox a postback is executed in order to send and retrieve data from client to server.

Well, fancybox takes a copy of the element and its children, then pastes the copied html to a fancybox instance and at the same time removes the source element html. This is how fancybox works.

When closing the fancybox, it doeas everything in reverse back to the original state. But this is not working when I close the fancybox after a postback.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, fancybox does not copy inline elements like your form, but moves elements in the DOM. It creates temporary element in the original position so it knows where to put back after closing. If you happen to change layout while fancybox is open, then temporary element might be lost (along with your content).

Comment: The simplest solution would be to display clone of your form as html content, for example, `$.fancybox.open({src : $('#yourForm').clone(true), type: 'html'});`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I'm not really changing any layouts. The only changes made are inside of the form/fancybox upon submit, like displaying of notification and such.

Comment: Since you did not provide any live demo, I can only guess that you are changing/refreshing/updating/whatever your layout/page/dom/element/whatever. Do you understand that without live demo it is just a guessing game?